# How can I merge a Pandas dataframes based on a substring from one of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes: df1 and df2

```
df1
                  School Conference
0              Air Force   Mt. West
1                  Akron        MAC
2  Alabama at Birmingham      C-USA
3                 Auburn   Sun Belt

df2
                           SCHOOL_NAME           RATE
0                    Auburn University           93.0
1                    Air Force Academy           53.0
2                           Birmingham           75.0
3                  University of Akron           77.0

I would like to get the output below, basically binding the `RATE` column from df2 into df1 based on substring from School column
                  School Conference  RATE
0              Air Force   Mt. West  53.0
1                  Akron        MAC  77.0
2  Alabama at Birmingham      C-USA  75.0
3                 Auburn   Sun Belt  93.0
```

I tried the code below but it's not working. When I run it, it seems to execute successfully, but nothing happens

```
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    if df1['School'][i] in df2['SCHOOL_NAME']:
       pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'School', right_on = 'SCHOOL_NAME')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to check if the columns from each dataframe are `in` each other (you also compare case-insensitively) and then merge:

```
df1['SCHOOL_NAME'] = df1['School'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in df2['SCHOOL_NAME']
                                                    if x in y or y in x]).str[0]
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left').drop('SCHOOL_NAME', axis=1) #can pass on='SCHOOL_NAME' to merge.
df1
Out[1]: 
                  School Conference  RATE
0              Air Force   Mt. West  53.0
1                  Akron        MAC  77.0
2  Alabama at Birmingham      C-USA  75.0
3                 Auburn   Sun Belt  93.0
```

You could also search case-insensitively by adding `.lower()` to `x` and `y`:

```
df1['SCHOOL_NAME'] = df1['School'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in df2['SCHOOL_NAME']
                                                    if x.lower() in y.lower()
                                                    or y.lower() in x.lower()]).str[0]
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left').drop('SCHOOL_NAME', axis=1) #can pass on='SCHOOL_NAME' to merge.
df1
Out[2]:
                  School Conference  RATE
0              Air Force   Mt. West  53.0
1                  Akron        MAC  77.0
2  Alabama at Birmingham      C-USA  75.0
3                 Auburn   Sun Belt  93.0
```

Single line of code per comment:

```
df1 = (df1.assign(SCHOOL_NAME = df1['School'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in df2['SCHOOL_NAME']
                                                    if x.lower() in y.lower()
                                                    or y.lower() in x.lower()]).str[0])
          .merge(df2, how='left').drop('SCHOOL_NAME', axis=1))
df1
Out[3]: 
                  School Conference  RATE
0              Air Force   Mt. West  53.0
1                  Akron        MAC  77.0
2  Alabama at Birmingham      C-USA  75.0
3                 Auburn   Sun Belt  93.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much, David. I appreciate it. This is does the job except one thing: I see the 3rd record returns NaN even though the string `Birmingham` was present. Any suggestion how I can improve the code to match the substring regardless of whether it's the beginning of the string?

Comment: @user3813620 good catch -- see my updated answer. Simply add `or y in x` to the end of the list comprehension.

Comment: That did it! You're a lifesaver. I had struggled with that part of the code for several hours. I appreciate it

Comment: Great answer!. Just curios @David Erickson - Is this possible to do within a single line using merge. i.e without the apply?

Comment: @sharathnatraj you could do it in a single line of code, but you would have to create a column to merge on and use `.apply` to create that.

Comment: @sharathnatraj I've shown you what that looks like in the third part of my answer.