# List comprehension to get rows that contain matching values from 2 seperate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So im trying to match 2 very different dataframes on a single column each containing numbers in string format. I need a concise, very fast solution so i tried using string comprehension and succeeded a few days back and then lost my work, im trying to recreate it.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col':['hey','hi','how ya durn']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col':['hey','hi','hello','what']})

df3=df2[[x for x in df2.col for y in df1.col if x in y]]
df3.head()
```

So i made this work the other day with 2 dataframes, both 20-30 columns, ~100k rows, different column data except for 1 column each, which im trying to match on.
I either get ValueError: `Item wrong length # instead of #.` or it takes an insane amount of time because the system im using is slow.

I know i need to use list comprehension or something faster, and i know `.apply()` takes too long. both of my matching columns contain 10-15 length numbers in string format. when i got it to work a few days back using a similar list comp one-liner it took seconds to complete and was perfect and now i  lost it and cant recreate it lol. any help is greatly appreciated.

(p.s. i may have used an `any()` statement in the list comp, and im 95% sure i used `if x in y`.)

Comment: You may have confused yourself. You are using "col" instead of "columns". Try `df3=df2[[x for x in df2.columns for y in df1.columns if x in y]]`

Comment: no im just trying to compare those 2 singular columns, similar to df1['col'], i use df1.col

Comment: then it appears I am the one has who confused myself :) -- what is your desired output? Can you provide a data example of desired output based off the input?

Comment: By any chance are you trying to do this? See my answer to I think a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345704/how-can-i-merge-a-pandas-dataframes-based-on-a-substring-from-one-of-the-columns/64345815#64345815

Comment: ha, i appreciate it anyways. I'm looking to get all of the rows from df2 where all of its 'col' column's values match df1's 'col' column's values. out of the 100kish rows in both of my dataframes im expecting around a thousand matches.

Comment: almost, it appears that hes trying to append a column based on matches, im trying to filter out rows that match. I'll try fitting that code to my problem real quick to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find strings in both columns with

```
df2[df2.col.isin(df1.col)]
```

Out:

```
   col
0  hey
1   hi
```

---

A solution with comprehension would be

```
df2[df2.col.isin([x for x in df2.col for y in df1.col if x in y])]
```

But this gets slow for larger columns

Comment: The only problems i had with `.isin()` was that it was slower than `if x in y` and it wouldnt check for substrings as I may need to match for `'how'` inside `'how ya durn'` as well.. if that makes sense.

Comment: Substring matching is a different question. Can you include this case in your example data and your expected output?